# Angular 5 Post is not working

Tags: angular

I have created application in angular 5. I am calling api with header it will not adding header in browser. It will show OPTION in header instead of it. 403 response. I have enabled the CORS in my service. When I call this post without header it works fine. Please let me know where is the problem.

```
 var headerOptions = new Headers();
        headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');    
        headerOptions.append('Auth-Token', '12345');

        var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headerOptions });
        return this.http.post("mydomain.com/api/getdata", null, requestOptions)
          .map((data: Response) => { return data.json() })
          .toPromise().then(x => {



          }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      }
```

Comment: have you try to empty form or empty object indtead of null.

Comment: Did you mentioned Token type??? Or is it not valid in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define request method twice, just do it like

```html
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {

  }

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers:Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('a20e6aca-ee83-44bc-8033-b41f3078c2b6:c199f9c8-0548-4be79655-7ef7d7bf9d20')); 
  }

  executeHttp() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var content = JSON.stringify({
      name: 'my name'
    });

    return this.http.post(
      'https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/', content, {
        headers: headers
      }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        data => { console.log(data); },
        err => { console.log(err); }
      );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: still got the same issue.

Comment: my mistake there is some issue in the API.

Answer (score 2):

> **Return a response with 200 status code for request method OPTIONS**

It is done by the browser to check whether the server allows the request method or not. After receiving 200 browser will send your actual request.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS
>
> https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/368

**If you are on PHP:**
You can intercept your requests in your API/Backend logic.I used a function in my project(Zend Framework3 - PHP)

```
    public function handlePreflightRequests(MvcEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'OPTIONS') {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $view = new JsonModel(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Checkpost passed'));
        $response->setContent($view->serialize());
        return $response;
    }
}
```

You can build a middleware in laravel or just check the request method in your controller send the success response and in your htaccess add this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, WU-Api-Key, WU-Api-Secret"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommended you to user httpclient instead of http. here i have make service and in that i have call api with header see my code it's working fine.

```
login(logins: Login): Observable<LoginApiResponse> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:54708/Account/LoginAPI';
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
      'cookies': '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=ttwetwtwe'
    })};
    return this._httpClient.post(url, logins, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map((myResponse => <LoginApiResponse> myResponse)));
  }
```

Above code is service.ts code and i have use it in my component.ts file as below.

```
this._Service.login(this.loginModel).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.status) {}
});
```

Hope this works!!!!
Thank you,

Comment: still the same issue. I have used the api with postman and it works fine but from angular post adding Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

I had also 403 with `this.http.post(url, null)` with CORS enabled on tomcat CorsFilter .

The same request `this.http.post(url, null)` with a clean tomcat worked fine.

with `this.http.post(url, {})` to the request is added 'Content-Type: application/json' then the request to tomcat with CorsFilter works for me.

requestOptions can be overwriten by some HttpInterceptor.